# WKWebView fails, didFailProvisionalNavigation Error 53

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview, xcode10.1

I'm getting an intermittent error when using a WKWebView. We call load(URLRequest) on the WKWebView, and we process through decidePolicyFor navigationAction and reply with an allow.

```
open func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
}
```

Immediately after, before any request is sent out over the network, didFailProvisionalNavigation is called with the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 “Software caused connection abort” UserInfo={_WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x280764dc0>, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A4437611-6DB9-4DF1-B437-256A180D42AC>.<83>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53}
```

It doesn't happen every time, it seems to only happen on the first request in the WKWebView, and most of the time I can only reproduce it once before it just works again for the next 10+.

If I simply run another .load(URLRequest) from didFailProvisionalNavigation, it loads without any issues.

How do I determine what is causing the Error 53? I really don't want to get into compiling webkit from source again.

Comment: have you tried on uiwebview ?

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated, and shouldn't be used any longer. It also doesn't work the same with cookies. The newer features added to WKWebView are too good to lose.

Comment: Just asking this thing is working there or not before ?

Comment: this is you can still use uiwebview its depcrecated but still available. the other thing is you are using cookies right ? if you are using cookies you must sync cookies with wkwebview.

Comment: By the way uiwebview work fine with cookies but wkwebview have their own space for cookies. please read  documentation.

Comment: Apple has responded to my bug report, marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @ataranlen Did Apple share any details about this error?

Comment: No, they only marked it as a duplicate, and closed it.